# NetSuite SuiteScript Const Declarations In Seperate File

Tags: suitescript

I have a NetSuite SuiteScript project consisting of a number of different javascript files, all with various functions. I'd like to have a single file containing a bunch of definitions of consts that all the files can access (if necessary, by passing a reference to the file or the object(s) in it around).

How do include the constants file in each javascript file so that all the functions within it can reference it and the values within it?

In each javascript file, how do I actually reference the values?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use AMD configurations for this. Lets say your constants file is named **myConstants.js**. Create an AMD file referencing your constants file like so:

amdConfig.config.json

```
{
  "paths": {
    "myConstants": "/path/to/myConstants"
  }
}
```

and then in your suitescript file, call it like so

```
/**
     * @NApiVersion 2.x
     * @NScriptType MapReduceScript
     * @NModuleScope Public
     * @NAmdConfig  /path/to/amdConfig.config.json
     */
    define(['myConstants', 'N/record'],
        /**
         *
         * @param myConstants
         * @param record
         */
        function (myConstants, record, ...
```